# Why External Path Length == Internal Path length + 2(Internal nodes)?

Tags: data-structures, tree, binary-tree, formula

I want to understand this intuitionally, not mathematically.
Facts I know :

1. This is for strictly binary tree(0 or 2 child).
2. The Number of Leaf Nodes is either half of total nodes or 1 more
   (Means it would be same as number of internal nodes or 1 more).

But by just using these 2, I'm unable to imagine this Formula. 
Appreciate your view and help.

Comment: Hint: **induction.** Is that enough?

Comment: Can you explain please

Comment: Do you understand the idea of proof by induction?